# How to deal with unsynchronized sensor data in a ROS2 bagfile?

Tags: imu, lidar, timestamp, bagfile, use-sim-time

I am using a ROS2 package for cooperative SLAM. After testing the package installation with official datasets like [GrAco](https://sites.google.com/view/graco-dataset) I recorded my own dataset with my vehicle. The main sensors I use are 3D-LiDAR and IMU.
When I try to run the package I get an error about unsychronized timestamps of the sensor data. In fact, the IMU and LiDAR data have completely different timestamps. I was not aware of this problem when I was recording.
Now I am looking for a solution to use this bag file anyway. Is there a way to synchronize the messages? Is using simulation time (use_sim_time) a worthwhile approach? If so, how?

And what are ways to record data correctly? How can I make sure that the data is recorded synchronously?